# Disney-Style Rendering, Eevee or Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, world

I have set out to create my own short movie within Blender, I'm creating the world settings at the moment. I have created the sky and I am about to create procedural clouds, but am un-sure as whether to follow a tutorial for Eevee clouds or Cycles clouds - because this could affect the end visual output.

The level of visual output I am aiming for is something along the lines of Disney or Next-Gen from Tangent Studios and Netflix.

[image: Moana - Disney]

My guess and first choice would be cycles, despite longer render times, just as it is more accurate with the lighting.

What render engine would be best for animation styles like that above?

Comment: Pixar Renderman....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest Cycles since PRMan is actually quite accurate in light calculate and the latest version also contain the ray tracing option/ability to render the scene.

[image]

Despite EEVEE is aiming for accurate light result, but it is still a little bit far away from the word *accurate*. It could speed up the scene setting and light setting, but you will need to switch to Cycles for a better result.

And Disney style use a lot of graphic effect and trick to mock the fluffy touch of the scene and also making the scene match the real world scene. Beside that, the final clip we saw has been post-processed in movie editor like Premiere or whatever they use. Making it more difficult to achieve the same image effect in Blender only.

So you might try using Cycles + Photoshop to tweak the style, not EEVEE unless you are familiar to deal with all the lighting problem that EEVEE might meet. And you can also use both EEVEE and Cycles to do different part of the scene rendering and merge them in post-processing stage.

Comment: you mean Cycles + After Effects, not Photoshop right?

Comment: @Luciano Depend on how you use Photoshop. Batch processing image sequence is not a bad choice if you know what you're doing. And if I just want to test whether the image is able to mimic the Disney one. I probably won't open a huge project only to see the effect but rather use Lightroom or CameraRaw to tweak the image.